# Optimize rows to columns conversion

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, inner-join

I have a big Oracle table (around 40 million rows) that looks like this:

```
ID  Name    Question Answer Reason      
3   Name1   1       Yes     blah blah
3   Name1   2       No      NA
3   Name1   3       No      NA
3   Name1   4       Yes     blah2
3   Name1   5       Yes     null
3   Name1   6       Yes     blah3
3   Name1   7       No      null
6   Name2   1       Yes     blah4444
6   Name2   2       No      null
6   Name2   3       Yes     blah3
6   Name2   4       NA      blah5
6   Name2   5       Yes     null
6   Name2   6       Yes     blah6
6   Name2   7       NA      null
```

I need one row per ID i.e. I will need to add columns for each question's answer (there are 7 questions per ID) and each question's reason. I need to make it look like this:

```
ID  Name    Q1     Q1-Reason    Q2    Q2-Reason   Q3    Q3-Reason    etc.
3   Name1   Yes    blah blah    No    null      
6   Name2   Yes    blah4444     No    null
```

My query currently looks like this:

```
select
   A.ID,A.NAME,B1.Q1,B1.Q1-REASON,B2.Q2,B2.Q2-REASON
from
   TABLENAME A
inner join
    (
    select distinct C1.ID,C1.ANSWER as Q1,C1.REASON as Q1-REASON
    from TABLENAME C1
    where C1.QUESTION=1
    ) B1 on B1.ID=A.ID
inner join
    (
    select distinct C2.ID,C2.ANSWER as Q2,C2.REASON as Q2-REASON
    from TABLENAME C2
    where C2.QUESTION=2
    ) B2 on B2.ID=A.ID
...
...
```

However, as the table is huge, this is taking a VERY long time to retrieve the data. Could someone suggest ways to optimize this query?

I'm on Oracle 10g and SQLDeveloper 4.0.2.15

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Mat! I just edited the question to include that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT
    TABLENAME.ID,
    TABLENAME.Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TABLENAME.Question=1 THEN TABLENAME.Answer ELSE NULL END) AS Q1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TABLENAME.Question=1 THEN TABLENAME.Reason ELSE NULL END) AS Q1_Reason,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TABLENAME.Question=2 THEN TABLENAME.Answer ELSE NULL END) AS Q2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TABLENAME.Question=2 THEN TABLENAME.Reason ELSE NULL END) AS Q2_Reason,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TABLENAME.Question=3 THEN TABLENAME.Answer ELSE NULL END) AS Q3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TABLENAME.Question=3 THEN TABLENAME.Reason ELSE NULL END) AS Q3_Reason
/*And so on*/
FROM
    TABLENAME
GROUP BY
    TABLENAME.ID,
    TABLENAME.Name
```

Comment: Hey Arion, Thanks for taking out the time to answer. I'm getting a "FROM keyword not found where expected" error. Could you tell me what I might be doing wrong? (I've got all the commas right)

Comment: I do not see any problem with the sql that I have answered with. Are you sure you have copied correct?

Comment: Just figured it out! Turns out you cannot use a hyphen in the AS section. For eg: "Max(blahblah) AS blah1-blah2" gives that error. Thanks again!

Comment: @Arion You're using `-` in your column aliases without quoting them. I suggest you use `Q1_Reason` instead of `Q1-Reason` etc.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt : True. Thank you did not see it. I updated the answer

Comment: This saved me so much time! Please let me know if I can ever help you out with something!